# I have build Terra Core using the `make` command provided in their docs, but it is showing me `terrad` command not found error

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I was following the documentation provided at https://docs.terra.money/docs/develop/how-to/terrad/install-terrad.html. After installation was completed I ran the `terrad version --long` command but it is showing `zsh: command not found: terrad` in the response. I have checked the $GOPATH is already set.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to add the `GOPATH` to your `$PATH` as well:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
```